# Selenium Drivers

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am initiating on browser automation tests using Selenium WebDriver, and while reading the tutorial I got blocked in a point.

In the Selenium WebDriver’s Drivers topic where it explains the pros and cons of each WebDriver implementation , it says the following about the HtmlUnit driver:

> HtmlUnit is a java based implementation of a WebBrowser without a GUI

So this means that this driver is equal to a browser application (like Mozzila,Opera or Chrome) without the GUI, we can only interact with it through methods

#### Firefox Driver

> Runs in a real browser and supports JavaScript
> Controls the Firefox browser using a Firefox plugin. The Firefox
> Profile that is used is stripped down from what is installed on the
> machine to only include the Selenium WebDriver.xpi (plugin). A few
> settings are also changed by default (see the source to see which
> ones) Firefox Driver is capable of being run and is tested on Windows,
> Mac, Linux. Currently on versions 3.6, 10, latest - 1, latest

What does this mean? To use this driver, do I have to install Firefox on my machine ?
When it says that it "runs in a real browser," does it mean that the multiple commands that we
use with the WebDriver interface are sent to the browser installed in our machine ?

If my assumption is correct, if we run the test on the Selenium-Server should the machine where the server is installed have Firefox installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes absolutely your assumption is correct. You need to install Firefox browser to use [FirefoxDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver) where as for [HtmlUnitDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) no browser needed.

See below link to see basic programs using HtmlUnitDriver & FirefoxDriver
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

In the same way you can run your tests in IE using [InternetExplorerDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).

Chrome, Opera drivers also available but not developed by [seleniumhq](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

You can download all types of driver from below link

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption in correct, If are using `Selenium` then you need to install the browser whereas `HtmlUnit` is Gui less (no GUI need to install)